# Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info' during xubuntu installation

Tags: xubuntu, asus

I'm trying to install xubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386 to my old Asus Eee pc AMD Athlon Processor 1.00 GHz, 992mb RAM, windows XP and I get this error during installation: Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Known bug, please re-download the ISO and verify MD5 hash

It appears this is a catch-all error usually thrown (shown) by Wubi not recognizing or reading some piece of data in the ISO used for installation, which in turn is caused by an error while downloading the ISO.

Please try separately downloading the 12.04 i386 desktop ISO, and verify that the MD5 hash matches. Then launch Wubi and point it to the downloaded ISO.

Comment: Correct, but you do not need to point Wubi to the ISO. Just put both files in the same directory and make sure the ISO has the same name as originally on the server. Don't rename it.